# How can I use python sockets over the internet

Tags: python, sockets

I'm building a simple chat app using python and want to use it over the internet. The server is starting on my local machine which has the port already forwarded, and to allow other users to access I provided them with the IP address I got from `www.whatismyip.com`. However, every time I test the application the client side gets this error :

```
client_socket.connect((ip,port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has 
failed to respond
```

The server side is like this :

```
import socket

shost = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
port = 5000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((ip,port))
server_socket.listen()
print(f"Server started on {ip}:{port}")
...
```

And the client side :

```
import socket

ip = "41.102.XXX.XX"
port = 5000

username = input("Username : ").encode('utf-8')
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((ip,port))
client_socket.send(username)
...
```

Comment: Does it take more than a minute to fail or it fails within seconds or less than a second?

Comment: It takes a minute or so yes

Comment: Something else. Then another possibility is that the client is sending the request anywhere but in the right direction (through the correct interface). Could you explain the layout better? where is the client?

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a router/NAT, and the PC where your server is has a LAN IP address, then you have to configure port forwarding in the router/NAT from port 5000 to port 5000 in the local IP address.
Other 2 possibilities: 1) the client is not sending the packets to the correct IP address, maybe not through the correct network interface. To check this you can use wireshark in the client machine. 2) there is some firewall rule in the server dropping the incoming messages. This is possible if you're getting the error after more than one minute. This usually happens when after the TCP SYN message there is no TCP SYN/ACK message. And not seeing the SYN/ACK is because the SYN message doesn't get to the server's listening port.

Comment: @mamokaze so use a command to check all open ports in the server machine. You have to see port 5000 listening (the command is netstat -na, in windows see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) If the port is open for listen then your have an error in the router configuration. Maybe you need to restart it? Another tool to test this is to use wireshark in the server and check the TCP SYN message arrives. If the port is open, I bet the SYN message is not arriving.

Comment: @mamokaze Something else. If it takes a few minutes to return with error then my previous comment may be not relevant (you can still check it to be sure). Another possibility is that the client is sending the request anywhere but in the right direction (through the correct interface). You can check this with Wireshark.